# passing a condition to Model.where to find records in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an instance in a method that is like this

```
@existinguser = User.where("trial_account_made_by = !nil? ")
```

I want to return all users where the trial_account_made_by ( a column in users table) is not nil. How do I pass that to where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `trial_account_made_by is not null` as:

```
@existinguser = User.where("trial_account_made_by is not null")
```

Answer (score 2):

For `Rails 4.x`, use

```
@existinguser = User.where.not(trial_account_made_by: nil)
```

For `Rails 3.x`, use

```
@existinguser = User.where('trial_account_made_by is not null')
```